# get VBox to NOT auto-resize children when elements are added

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, jfoenix

So I have a scrollable message system using this structure:

[image: Structure]

The HBoxes contain a message, there are multiple.

The problem is, when more HBoxes/messages are added, they are shrunk to one line, and the labels inside them are overrun. **I don't want this.**

Here are examples of how it looks when the hboxes are **not** shrunk:
[image]

And this is how it looks when there are **many enough** messages for it shrink the hboxes:
[image]

It's either an FXML property I haven't set, or some other solution to the problem. Much appreciated!

EDIT:
To clarify, Messages that have been shrunk can only show one line of text.

Comment: Do you have a max width defined for the HBox?

Comment: Yes @ItachiUchiha they are set to 250, but as you see it wraps the text and makes a new line.

Comment: Just to clarify things, you add an HBox which contain a Label everytime you have a message ? And want the result to be/stay like the first image ?

Comment: Yes @BoHalim the problem is that the messages try to fit the vbox, like it does not know that it is scrollable, and therefore shrinks